# Error al crear un Adapter en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

### Error al transferir en RecyclerView de un activty a un fragmento

> Al crear un Adapter para el RecylcerView, me da el siguiente error: Type mismatch: inferred type is HomeFragment but Context! was expected. En principio quería el RecyclerView en un Activity pero finalmente lo pasé a un fragmento, y en este proceso me da el siguiente error.

```
class MainAdapter(private val context: HomeFragment):RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {

private var dataList = mutableListOf<Hobbie>()

fun setListData(data:MutableList<Hobbie>){
    dataList = data
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false)
    return MainViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if (dataList.size > 0) {
        dataList.size
    } else {
        0
    }
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val user:Hobbie = dataList[position]
    holder.bindView(user)
}

inner class MainViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    fun bindView(user:Hobbie){
        itemView.txt_title.text = user.nombre
    }
}
```

}

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var adapter: MainAdapter
private val ViewModels : MainViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    adapter = MainAdapter(this)

    rvHobbies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    rvHobbies.adapter = adapter
    observeData()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

fun observeData(){
    ViewModels.fetchHobbieData().observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.setListData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Creo que el error es en el requiereContext pero no estoy seguro.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var adapter: MainAdapter
private val ViewModels : MainViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    adapter = MainAdapter(this)

    rvHobbies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    rvHobbies.adapter = adapter
    observeData()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

fun observeData(){
    ViewModels.fetchHobbieData().observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.setListData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

}

Aquí dejo el HomeFramgent

> > Dejo también el HomeFragment, que es donde quiero el RecyclerView. He cambiado aún así e contexto, pero sigue dando error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactamente, el error se debe a que requieres definir el contexto para inflar la vista, para obtener el contexto usa `parent.context` :

```
  val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).
            inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false) as View
```